# AngularJS - Save user preferences in a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my partial view `settings.html`

```
<div ng-controller="settingsController">

    <h3>General Settings</h3>
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
        <tr class="success">
            <td class = "col-xs-3">Language:</td>
            <td class = "col-xs-9">Gmail display language:
                <select ng-model = "userPreferences.selectedLang" ng-options="language for language in languages">
                    <option value = ""> Choose a language </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="danger">
            <td class = "col-xs-3">Conversation View</td>
            <td class = "col-xs-9">
                <input type = "radio" name = "conversation" id = "converseOn" ng-model="userPreferences.converse.state" value = "on" checked>
                <label for="converseOn"> Conversation view on </label>

                <aside>
                    <input type = "radio" name = "conversation" ng-model="userPreferences.converse.status" value = "off" id = "converseOff">
                    <label for="converseOff"> Conversation view off </label>
                </aside>
        </tr>

        <tr class="info">
            <td class = "col-xs-3">Maximum page size: </td>
            <td class = "col-xs-9"> Show conversations per page
                <select ng-model = "userPreferences.selectedNumber" ng-options="conversation for conversation in conversations">
                    <option value = ""> Choose the no.of conversations to display </option>
                </select>

                <aside id = "pageSize" > Show contacts per page
                    <select ng-model = "selectedNumberContacts" ng-options="contact for contact in contacts">
                        <option value = ""> Choose the no.of contacts to display </option>
                    </select>
                </aside>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>

    <div class="form-actions" >
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click = "setPreference()">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the `settingsController.js`

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var settingController = function (fetchDataService, $scope, savePreferenceService) {
        var url = 'app/mock/settings.json';
        fetchDataService.getContent(url)
            .then(function(response){
                $scope.contacts = response.data.contacts;
                $scope.languages = response.data.languages;
                $scope.conversations = response.data.conversations;
                $scope.undoSend = response.data.undoSend;
            });

        $scope.userPreferences = {
            selectedLang : '',

             converse : {
                  state: 'on'
                 },

              selectedNumber : 0
          }


       $scope.setPreference = function () {
            savePreferenceService.selectedPreferences($scope.userPreferences.selectedLang, $scope.userPreferences.converse.state, $scope.userPreferences.selectedNumber);
        }
    };

    angular.module('iisEmail')
        .controller ('settingsController',
        ['fetchDataService', '$scope', 'savePreferenceService', settingController]);
}());
```

This is the `savePreferenceService.js`

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var savePreferenceService = function () {
        this.selectedPreferences = function (selectedLang, converse, selectedNumber) {
            this.selectedLang = selectedLang;
            this.converse = converse;
            this.selectedNumber = selectedNumber;

            console.log(this.selectedLang);
            console.log(this.converse);
            console.log(this.selectedNumber);
        }
  };    

      angular.module('iisEmail')
        .service ('savePreferenceService', savePreferenceService);
}());
```

So, basically my goal is to save user preferences when the `Save changes` button is clicked.

To achieve this functionality, I have defined an object in the controller, and binded its properties to the view using `ng-model`. When the save changes button is clicked, the `setPreference()` function is called which makes a service `savePreferenceService` call. The `savePreferenceService` saves options chosen by the user. Everything works as expected.

I just want to know if there is a better way of doing this (in terms of best practices). My requirement is to save the options chosen by a user in a service.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really seeing how data could possibly be saved when you do something like a page refresh, unless you're not showing the code here?

If you want to preserve data saves whenever the user visits your page, you can always use localstorage, which stores info in the user's browser. There are various web tutorials on how to utilize localstore, but this website (which didn't take long to find), includes and extends localstorage as a service, and to use that service as a way to store data in there.

http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/
(code below is taken from this link)

```
angular.module('ionic.utils', [])

.factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
    return {
        set: function(key, value) {
        $window.localStorage[key] = value;
    },
    get: function(key, defaultValue) {
        return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
    },
    setObject: function(key, value) {
        $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    },
    getObject: function(key) {
        return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
    }
}}]);
```

and to use this service:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'ionic.utils'])

    .run(function($localstorage) {

        $localstorage.set('name', 'Max');
        console.log($localstorage.get('name'));
        $localstorage.setObject('post', {
            name: 'Thoughts',
            text: 'Today was a good day'
        });

    var post = $localstorage.getObject('post');
    console.log(post);
});
```

Or you could just use localstorage the old fashion way using plain old javascript..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you have is working for you. Not sure exactly what you  mean by 'I just want to know if there is a better way of doing this' since that is pretty subjective.

What I do notice right away is that the current implementation makes your user preferences session based because they are only retained in-memory, meaning that if the user uses the app, makes changes to the preferences, leaves the app and returns, the changes are lost. If you need to preserve them, then I would suggest using LocalStorage or actually storing them in some type of data store (file, database, ...).

Also, I would suggest making your service the owner of the preferences data instead of splitting the responsibility between the controller and the service. What I mean by that is that the default preferences are owned by the controller, but only when updated do they make it to the service. What I would do instead is

- change the service to have a get method and a set method. Perhaps getPreferences() and setPreferences(...).
- change the controller to call the getPreferences method instead of assigning a static preferences object
- call the setPreferences method from the controller's setPreference method

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was helpful. I refactored my controller and service as you suggested. However, now I am having trouble making `ng-model` bind to the `userPreferences` object in the service.

Comment: You'll have to post code to see what the issue is, but once you have the getPreferences service method, all you should need to do in the controller is set you userPreferences as:  $scope.userPreferences = savePreferenceService.getPreferences();

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks.